# How to change wordpress theme categories title tag (entry.title) from <h1> to <h2>

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

this is the [webpage](https://www.vgopromo.com/esports/)
same thing happens for [vgo 2023](https://www.vgopromo.com/2023/).

so I have multiple h1 titles on the same page

see image:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO7G3.png)

what do I need to change and the h1 tags into h2 tags?

to the answer bellow image:
[this is how my content.php looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o95ad.png)

code for content.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package electro
 */

$additional_post_classes = apply_filters( 'electro_additional_post_classes', array('') );

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $additional_post_classes ); ?>>

    <?php
    /**
     * @hooked electro_post_header() - 10
     * @hooked electro_post_meta() - 20
     * @hooked electro_post_content() - 30
     */
    do_action( 'electro_loop_post' );
    ?>

</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

can anybody help out with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your theme function, see file content.php in the template-parts folder, and change tag h1 to h2 as needed. See attachment.
[image]

Comment: my content.php looks something else

Comment: you could had least paste the code instead of this image

Comment: code don't work also